# can't reset label text (customtkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I tried to implement a condition to check if the entered task is an empty string. In that case a label with "Can't enter empty string!" is packed. When the user enters a valid string, the empty_label should be "" (empty string)
My code:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

def add_todo():
    task = entry.get()
    empty_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Can't enter empty string!", width=500)
    if task == "":
        empty_label.pack(pady=20)
        return
    new_label = ctk.CTkLabel(scrollable_frame, text=task)
    new_label.pack()
    entry.delete(0, ctk.END)
    empty_label.configure(text="")

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry("750x450")
root.title("Todo APP")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

title_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Daily Tasks", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))
title_label.pack(padx=10, pady=(40, 20))

scrollable_frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(root, width=500, height=200)
scrollable_frame.pack()

entry= ctk.CTkEntry(scrollable_frame, placeholder_text="Add task")
entry.pack(fill="x")

btn = ctk.CTkButton(root, text="Add", width=500, command=add_todo)
btn.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried this
`empty_label.configure(text="")`

For some reason it doesn't work. I even tried to do same in Tkinter and I got same result.

Comment: Please add more details regarding "For some reason it doesn't work." Which part "doesn't work"? What is your expected behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are doing is creating the new label and then returning with every empty input.
You need to precreate the button before the funtion so that the function can change the text of the previously created button, here's the code:

```py
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry("750x450")
root.title("Todo APP")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

title_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Daily Tasks", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))
title_label.pack(padx=10, pady=(40, 20))

scrollable_frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(root, width=500, height=200)
scrollable_frame.pack()

entry= ctk.CTkEntry(scrollable_frame, placeholder_text="Add task")
entry.pack(fill="x")

def add_todo():
    task = entry.get()
    if task == "":
        empty_label.configure(text="Can't enter empty string!") # change the precreated button's text
        return
    new_label = ctk.CTkLabel(scrollable_frame, text=task)
    new_label.pack()
    entry.delete(0, ctk.END)
    empty_label.configure(text=" ") # change the precreated button's text

btn = ctk.CTkButton(root, text="Add", width=500, command=add_todo)
btn.pack(pady=20)

empty_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="", width=500) # | precreate the button outside of the function
empty_label.pack(pady=20)                            # |

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this could solve your problem!

Comment: What do you mean by resetting the label, @toyotaSupra ? They are trying to reset the label and emptying it. My way works fine, could you perhaps explain what you / they meant by resetting?

Comment: Sorry, I was using wrong platform. Please accept my apology.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this way: you've used `pack` in the function `add_todo()` But not just configured the text. I guess you want the empty_label widget should not be visible by default rather not showing a plain text by default. So, I've added a function `unpack()` and modified the code. Please no that you don't need to use the `return` statement in the function `add_todo`

```
import customtkinter as ctk

def unpack(): empty_label.pack_forget()
def add_todo():
    task = entry.get()
    
    if task == "":
        #pack empty_lable
        empty_label.pack()
    else:
        #unpack empty_label
        unpack()
        new_label = ctk.CTkLabel(scrollable_frame, text=task)
        new_label.pack()
        entry.delete(0, ctk.END)
        
        

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry("750x450")
root.title("Todo APP")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)



title_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Daily Tasks", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))
title_label.pack(padx=10, pady=(40, 20))

scrollable_frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(root, width=500, height=200)
scrollable_frame.pack()

entry= ctk.CTkEntry(scrollable_frame, placeholder_text="Add task")
entry.pack(fill="x")

#create an empty_label with default text 'Can't Enter Empty label and don't pack
empty_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Can't Enter Empty label", width=500)




btn = ctk.CTkButton(root, text="Add", width=500, command=add_todo)
btn.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```